# Connect 2 phaser sprites using p2 revolute constraints without apply force

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, physics, phaser-framework, p2

So I have sprites that I want to connect using p2.js' revolute constraints. My current implementation applys force to the sprites as soon as the constraint is created.
How can I avoid this behavior?
If it can't be avoided is there another way to connect 2 sprites with each other horizontally?
**EDIT:**

```
var Game = {

preload: function() {
    game.load.image('tree00', './imgs/tree/tree-00.png');
    game.load.image('tree01', './imgs/tree/tree-01.png');
    game.load.image('tree02', './imgs/tree/tree-02.png');
    game.load.image('tree03', './imgs/tree/tree-03.png');
    game.load.image('tree04', './imgs/tree/tree-04.png');
    game.load.image('tree05', './imgs/tree/tree-05.png');

    game.load.spritesheet('present', './imgs/dude.png', 32, 48);
},

create: function() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    game.physics.p2.gravity.y = 300;
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#aaffee';

    treeCollsionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();
    presentCollisionGroup = game.physics.p2.createCollisionGroup();

    this.createPresent(game.world.width * 0.21, game.world.height * 0.6);
    this.createTree(6, game.world.width * 0.2, game.world.height * 0.8);

    //presentCollisionGroup.collides(treeCollsionGroup);

    connection[0] = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(treeParts[treeParts.length - 1], [(treeParts[treeParts.length - 1].width)/2, treeParts[treeParts.length - 1].height], present, [-present.width/2, treeParts[treeParts.length - 1].height], maxForce);
    connection[1] = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(treeParts[treeParts.length - 1], [(treeParts[treeParts.length - 1].width)/2, 0], present, [-present.width/2, 0], maxForce);
}, 

createTree: function(length, xAnchor, yAnchor) {
    var lastSprite;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {          
        newSprite = game.add.sprite(xAnchor, yAnchor - i*100, 'tree0' + i);
        newSprite.scale.x = game.world.width/1920;
        newSprite.scale.y = game.world.width/1920;

        game.physics.p2.enable(newSprite, true);
        if (i != length-1) {
            newSprite.body.setRectangle(game.world.width * 0.10, newSprite.height * 0.15);
        } else {
            newSprite.body.setRectangle(newSprite.width * 0.8, newSprite.height * 0.8);
        }
        newSprite.body.setCollisionGroup(treeCollsionGroup);

        if(i === 0) {
            newSprite.body.static = true;
        }

        if (lastSprite) {
            switch(i) {
                case 1: constraint = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(newSprite, [0, 0], lastSprite, [0, -lastSprite.height * 0.62], maxForce);
                        treeConstraints.push(constraint);
                        break;
                case 2: constraint = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(newSprite, [0, 0], lastSprite, [0, -lastSprite.height * 0.285], maxForce);
                        treeConstraints.push(constraint);
                        break;
                case 3: constraint = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(newSprite, [0, 0], lastSprite, [0, -lastSprite.height * 0.425], maxForce);
                        treeConstraints.push(constraint);
                        break;
                case 4: constraint = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(newSprite, [0, 0], lastSprite, [0, -lastSprite.height * 0.4], maxForce);
                        treeConstraints.push(constraint);
                        break;
                case 5: constraint = game.physics.p2.createRevoluteConstraint(newSprite, [0, 0], lastSprite, [0, -lastSprite.height * 0.55], maxForce);
                        treeConstraints.push(constraint);
                        break;
            }
        }
        lastSprite = newSprite;
        treeParts.push(newSprite);
        newSprite.body.collides(treeCollsionGroup);
    }
},

createPresent: function(xAnchor, yAnchor) {
    present = game.add.sprite(game.world.width * 0.21, game.world.height * 0.6, 'present');
    game.physics.p2.enable(present, true);
    present.scale.x = game.world.width/1920;
    present.scale.y = game.world.width/1920;
    present.body.setRectangle(present.width, present.height);
    present.body.data.gravityScale = 0;
    present.body.setCollisionGroup(presentCollisionGroup);
}
}
```

I cut the less important code out so it would not be too much (it already is). 
Basically what I'm doing is: I create a tree and connecting the parts using revolute constraints so they behave like a tree in the real world (for example in the wind).
Than I create the present which is basically a sprite that should be horizontally connected to the top of the tree. Therefore I use 2 revolute constraint one for the topmost point between the sprites and one for the bottommost. (I know it's kind of dirty code)
After I create these constraints and the present gets connected to the top of the tree the tree starts shaking and collapses (like it should). But I don't want this behaviour.
Maybe a lock constraint is what I'm looking for, I have to look into this.
**Edit 2:**
After taking a look at lock constraints I realized that this is what I'm looking for. But even lock constraints are collapsing the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your issue but have you tried [Prismatic](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.P2.PrismaticConstraint.html) or even [Lock](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Physics.P2.LockConstraint.html) Constraint? Can give us some code or even codepen example so we may be able to help you better?

Comment: can you take a look at it again?

Comment: well, i don't really know, because i'm not that experienced with constraints, but maybe you have to use a spring just to negate the initial force? Check [this](http://www.inkfood.com/create-a-car-with-phaser/) (the car example) if it helps or someone else could give you a solution.